# How to set gravity in textInputLayout edit text of google's material design

Tags: android, xml

I want to make the gravity of my edit text of material design to top.
how to do that because I am not getting the attribute in the attribute section.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/etCreatePost"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:hint="What do you want to talk about?"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        style="@style/edit_text_gravity">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: It may be layout_gravity instead of just gravity

Comment: @CCT I can not use gravity or layout_gravity in the textinputLayout

Comment: Both android:gravity and android:layout_gravity are available in the TextInputEditText's attributes.

Comment: @CCT yeah it is working. Actually I don't know why it was not auto suggesting me when I was typing gravity. So I thought it is not available in the TextInputEditText.